# How to toggle class name with multiple <li> option?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple `<li>` and would like to set className="active" to the one which is clicked. But keep in mind i m gonna call href to different route. Now lets say the route is same on all li.

following is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Sidebar extends Component{
render(){
    return(
            <aside className="main_sidebar">
                    <ul >
                        <li title="Home" className="active"><a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-home "></i></a></li>
                        <li title="Irrigation Pump"><a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-battery-2"></i></a></li>
                        <li title="Drinking Water"><a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-truck"></i></a></li>
                        <li title="Patvan"><a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a></li>
                        <li title="Rooftop"><a href="/dashboard"><i className="fa fa-sun-o"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
        )
}
}

export default Sidebar;
```

following img shows the css which gets applied to `<li>`.

Thanks.

[image: sidebar]

Comment: If you use the `Link` component from `React Router`, it will handle this automatically. Do you have react router in you project?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `<NavLink/>` from **react-router-dom**, in which you have a prop called **activeClassName**, this is a prop which takes in **CSS ClassName** which you would like to apply for an active link and this is managed automatically by `NavLink`.

This is a sample code of a **reusable wrapper component**, you can pass the link in has **props**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import classes from './NavigationItem.css';

const navigationItem = ( props ) => (
    <li title="Home" className="active">
        <NavLink 
            to={props.link}
            activeClassName={classes.active}>{props.children}</NavLink>
    </li>
);

export default navigationItem;
```

This can be consumed like this

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './NavigationItems.css';
import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem/NavigationItem';

const navigationItems = () => (
    <aside className="main_sidebar">
       <ul className={classes.NavigationItems}>
           <NavigationItem link="/" exact>Burger Builder</NavigationItem>
           <NavigationItem link="/orders">Orders</NavigationItem>
           <NavigationItem link="/Auth">Auth</NavigationItem>
       </ul>
 </aside>
);

export default navigationItems;
```

**Note:** In my code for activeClassName I am using CSS Modules, feel free to change it though!